# Create an SQLite Connection in a static method in Java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I want to create a static method in Java to abstract connecting to an SQLite database

Here is my code for the Connect Class:

```
public class Connect {

    public static Connection Connect(String connection, Boolean create) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, FileNotFoundException {

        Connection conn = null;

        try {

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

            if(create == false){

                try {

                    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(connection);
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+connection);

                } catch(Exception NoDB) {
                    throw NoDB;
                }


            } else {

                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+connection);

            }

            return conn;

        } catch(Exception e){

            if(conn != null){

                conn.close();

            }

            throw e;

        }

    }
}
```

I want to be able to call the Connect Class like this

```
Connection conn = Connect();
```

I am using Intellij and the IDE Keeps suggesting this code to

```
(Connection) conn = new Connect();
```

I made the methods static and I am importing the Class. What am I doing wrong how to make the code work that way. I am return a type connection from the static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating a `static` method for acquiring the connection, then you shouldn't be creating an *instance* of the utility class (using the `new` operator) in the first place.

Static methods are accessed by the class name, so just use `Connection conn = Connect.Connect(...)` instead. And note that according to Java style conventions, method names should start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: So I have to use the namespace or i guess in Java its the "class name" of the Class then. Could I create that static Connect() method as a global function?

Comment: There are no global functions in Java. You need to `import` classes individually. Static members can also be imported to save some boilerplate, e.g. `import static com.mypackage.Connect.connect;` after which you don't need to specify the class name to invoke that method within the importing class.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you can do static imports, I am coldfusion programmer and I started with C# I am learning Java so I can use it in conjunction with Coldfusion. C# just added static imports in version 6. How long has java been able to do it?